# undefined method `rebuild' for #<BottleSpecification:0x00000000e9fdb8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, homebrew, linuxbrew

I have installed LinuxBrew in Ubuntu. After that on running the following command-

```
   brew install rbenv ruby-build
```

I get the following error:

```
   Error: undefined method `rebuild' for #<BottleSpecification:0x00000000e9fdb8>
```

How do you resolve this?Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating *brew* first and then installing *rbenv* followed by *ruby-build*:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install rbenv
$ brew install ruby-build
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!